# Change color of check mark in grid control using style attribute

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, devexpress

I have a WPF application using MVVM design pattern. One of the user controls has a grid control bound to a data table in my view model. One of the columns of the grid control are of type bool. So the Grid control displays them as a check box column giving user functionality to check/uncheck the box. Now what I want to achieve is different colors for different rows of the grid control based on certain conditions. For this I define a static resource - Style in the resource dictionary of my `UserControl`. The code is given below :

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
      <Style x:Key="ForeroundStyle" TargetType="{x:Type dxg:GridRowContent}">
         <Setter Property="Foreground">
            <Setter.Value>
               <MultiBinding Converter ="{StaticResource MyConverter}" ConverterParameter="1">
                  <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                     <Binding Path="DataContext"/>
                     <Binding Path="Row"/>
                  </MultiBinding.Bindings>
               </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </Style>
   </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

My problem is that all the other column elements of the grid control get the specified color by the converter, however the check mark in the check box has a default color value which is not changed. How can I achieve the same for the check mark in the check box. Any suggestions would help!

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the color of the check mark in a CheckBox, you can follow these three steps.

First of all extend the CheckBox control by adding a new dependecy property in this way:

```
public class ExCheckBox : CheckBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CheckMarkColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CheckMarkColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(ExCheckBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black));

    public Brush CheckMarkColor
    {
        get
        {
            return (Brush)GetValue(CheckMarkColorProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(CheckMarkColorProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Second step: you can use a CheckBox style. You can find a sample [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752319(v=vs.85).aspx). Now you need just to bind your `CheckMarkColorProperty` to the "CheckMark". In the sample you need to modify the `Path` object in this way:

```
<Path Width="7" Height="7" 
    x:Name="CheckMark"
    SnapsToDevicePixels="False" 
    Stroke="{TemplateBinding CheckMarkColor}"
    StrokeThickness="2"
    Data="M 0 0 L 7 7 M 0 7 L 7 0" />
```

Of course the style has to be "linked" to the `ExCheckBox` control.

Last step: you can bind the ExCheckBox in your grid in order to change its check mark color depending on your logic.